# How do you dynamically create difference- or delta- columns in a data.frame?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, vectorization, difference

My `dataframe` has column names of outstanding balance from `Balance`, `Balance1`, `Balance2`,...,`Balance36`.

I want to add a column for the delta between each month, i.e. `Delta2` = `Balance2` - `Balance1`

How can I simplify by method below.

```
dataset$delta1 = apply(dataset[, c("Balance1","Balance")], 1, function(x){x[2]-x[1]})
dataset$delta2 = apply(dataset[, c("Balance2","Balance1")], 1, function(x){x[2]-x[1]})
...
dataset$delta35 = apply(dataset[, c("Balance35","Balance34")], 1, function(x){x[2]-x[1]})
dataset$delta36 = apply(dataset[, c("Balance36","Balance35")], 1, function(x){x[2]-x[1]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It boils down to a one-liner. First, name your dataset something short, `df` is the usual name. Then, use direct subtraction; there's zero need to call `apply()` to subtract one column from another:

```
df$delta1 <- df[,"Balance1"] - df[,"Balance"]
df$delta2 <- df[,"Balance2"] - df[,"Balance1"]
...
df$delta35 <- df[,"Balance35"] - df[,"Balance34")]
df$delta36 <- df[,"Balance36"] - df[,"Balance35")]
```

But since the whole computation has a regular structure, we're really only talking about generating a Nx36 array of differences, so use numeric column indices. Say your "Balance*" column indices are (50:85) and your  delta_cols are 100:135, or whatever. Then the indices for LHS of your "Balance*" subtraction are `balance_lhs <- (50:84)` and RHS indices are `(51:85)`, or just `((50:84)+1)` (remember that most operators like addition vectorize in R)

So your Nx36 array can be generated by just the one-liner:

```
df[,delta_cols] <- df[,(balance_lhs+1)] - df[,balance_lhs]
```

And you can compute `delta_cols <- which(colnames(df) == c("delta1",...,"delta36")` programmatically, to avoid magic-number column indices in your code.

Comment: If the "delta" column names don't exist already would I need to create them first or can it be done dynmaically in the same one line of code.  i.e. my original df includes monthly balance columns not delta columns.

Comment: @Adam: if the cols don't exist, yes you can create them while simultaneously assigning them: `df[,c("delta1",...,"delta36")] <- ...`. This works when you reference non-existing cols by column-name, but not by indices. Alternatively it may be easier (and makes things more parameterizable by width) to create a df with numerical col-indices. You can always assign `colnames(df)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lapply` to calculate delta for all 36 comparisons in one line.

```
# Sample data (37 columns, labelled Balance, Balance1, ...)
set.seed(2017);
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(37 * 100), ncol = 37));
colnames(df) <- paste("Balance", c("", seq(1:36)), sep = "");

# List of difference vectors (36 distance vectors, labelled delta1, ...)
lst <- lapply(2:ncol(df), function(i) df[, i] - df[, i - 1]);
names(lst) <- paste("delta", seq(1:36), sep = "");

# Combine with original dataframe
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    df,
    as.data.frame(lst));
```

Comment: Calling `lapply()` will be slower than straight subtraction of matrices

Comment: @smci True. When I posted my solution yours didn't include the direct matrix indexing yet which you added later.